# Sonarqube, get a difference of issues between 2 runs

Tags: sonarqube

I am using

> /api/issues/search API

, but the problem i have is i want to get **diff of issues in 2 runs**, so i was thinking about using the **issue key**, this API returns, but problem is when I delete the project and run again, all the api keys are new, so i wanted to know whether these issues keys are generated randomnly ? or they have some formula, and if needed to change it, where can i do so ? Can you point me to right location in code ?

Talking about this issue key, which comes in result JSON :

> key: "165a4b4a-e8e2-4a54-968d-21a362dbc818"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue key is a randomly generated UUID that is by definition immutable (so you can't change it).

If you want to computing the diff between 2 runs of the same project, you have to:

- list all issues of the project (unresolved & resolved issues)
- check the changelog of each issue to see what its status was at analysis N and analysis N+1

Comment: Hey so I have a problem, that I copy Sonar data from Sonar DB to a redshift DB, because of that i lose data from Sonar, so I want to calculate diff from that Redshift, so i want to generate something like UUID, can i ask you what all parameters you guys have taken to make sure that if i move method or move the issue few lines above or below, the key remains same

Comment: We're using java.util.UUID, so you will never be able to generate the same UUID because this is not linked to any property of an issue.